# Convert AM/PM to lowercase in datepicker.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

In `pickadatejs`, is it possible to get lowercase format (am/pm) instead of uppercase format (AM/PM), with minimum configuration as possible?

Comment: It's in the documentation http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#formats

Comment: Could also just use CSS `text-transform: lowercase` on the am/pm text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> The formatLabel option is unique. It can contain HTML and it can also be a function if you want to create the label during run-time:

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
  // Escape any “rule” characters with an exclamation mark (!).
  format: 'T!ime selected: h:i a',
  formatLabel: '<b>h</b>:i <!i>a</!i>',
  formatSubmit: 'HH:i',
  hiddenPrefix: 'prefix__',
  hiddenSuffix: '__suffix'
})
```

In formatLabel, you can simply use `.toLowerCase()`, since it accepts a function.